# Force an EditText to scroll down to a certain spot

Tags: java, android

How would I make an multi-line EditText with a vertical scroll bar go down to a certain spot? I want to do this inside of the Java code, and I'd prefer to do it with an EditText, but I'd be willing to use a ScrollView if I need to.

The EditText XML:

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/theTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textMultiLine"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:width="0dp" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [scrollTo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollTo%28int,%20int%29) api from the view.